# Why REC languages is undecidable under emptiness and finiteness?

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, halting-problem, decidability

Membership problem of Recursive languages are decidable.

**My approach:**

Let $L$ be a recursive language and $M$ be the Turing Machine that accepts  it.
For string $w,$ if $w ∈ L,$ then $M$ halts in final state. If $w ∉ L,$ then $M$ halts in non-final state. (halts always!). That's why Recursive languages are decidable for Membership problem

My question is in same logic, why finiteness, emptiness is undecidable? Don't want any concrete proof. I just want brief concepts like my approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To decide whether a language is empty you'd have to run $M$ on **all** possible input strings and verify that $M$ always rejects. How are you going to do that in a way that ensures that your algorithm always terminates?

Similarly, to decide whether $L$ is finite you'd have to check that $M$ rejects almost always, i.e., always except for at most a finite number of inputs.

Formally, you can reduce the halting problem to problem of deciding whether a language $L$, encoded as a decider machine for $L$, is empty/finite.

For example, given Turing machine $T$ you can define a Turing machine $T'$ that takes a string $x$ as input and simulates $T$ on empty input for $|x|$ steps. If the simulation ends, $T'$ accepts. Otherwise $T'$ rejects.
Then, you can decide if $T$ halts on empty input by checking if the language recognized by $T'$  is not empty.

Comment: one thing tell reduction only possible to undecidable to undecidable? Reduction Decidable to undecidable possible?

Comment: empty input means

Comment: I'm not sure how it helps, but yes: it is possible to reduce a decidable language to an undecidable one. Empty input means that the contents of the tape are the empty word, usually denoted with $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Your answer is good.. I need understand your last paragraph...

Comment: Could you delete last 2 paragraph which is unnecessary.. And first two paragraph is my answer.

Comment: The first two paragraphs are only intuition. In mathematics, intuition is important, but only proof counts.

Comment: @Steven by your two intuition membership of recursive is also undecidable. Because if the element exist in last element of infinite set. So how membership of recursive is decidable?

Comment: Fist of all, as Yuval Filmus said, reasoning and drawing parallels using *just* intuition can be misleading. You should try to formally prove your intuitions. Anyway, even according to my intuitive explanation, membership in recursive languages is *not* undecidable since it suffices to use $M$ to test whether **a single input word**  is in the language. Since $M$ is a decider for the language, $M$ will always halt. The problem arises when you need to test **an infinite** number of words.